# Creé un repositorio de mi proyecto pero lo hice en una carpeta que no es la raíz. Hay solución para que el repo englobe todo mi proyecto?

Tags: git, github

un esquema de mis carpetas

proyecto
Carpeta api
Carpeta client
aqui dentro de la carpeta client inicie el repo, asi que no va a agarrar la carpeta api

Comment: Ya hiciste commits? Si no has hecho nada,, simplemente borra el directorio `.git`  del subdirectorio y haz `git init` donde corresponde o mueve el directorio `.git` al directorio raíz del proyecto .... No es como que si git va a dejar de funcionar por hacer esos malabares

Comment: @eftshift0 si ya hice commit, lo subi tambien en github. hago lo que me dices y borro el proyecto en github o que hago?

Comment: Si ya hiciste commit..... No borres.

Comment: Doy una respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es un proyecto que apenas va comenzando y no te quieres complicar la vida, entonces engaña a git... Primero, hazle creer que vas a borrar todo lo que está en el directorio donde está funcionando actualmente:

```
git rm --cached *
```

Con eso git va a borrar todos los archivos del indice, pero los deja en el proyecto sin tocarlos.

Entonces en ese punto mueve el directorio `.git` a la raíz del proyecto.

Si haces un git status te debe indicar que todo está untracked con unos archivos borrados por acometer..... Si en este punto agregas el directorio de lo que antes tenías en git entonces git se debe dar cuenta de que lo que hiciste fue "renombrarlos".... Y en este punto puedes agregar las demás cosas y acometer..... Y empujar.... No es "elegante" pero funciona y no pierdes la historia de lo que hiciste hasta ahora.